# Variable value not being saved in function

Tags: javascript

I want my filters variable to update, my guess is it's re-initializing as the set value every time the function is called, whenever i try to declare it outside of the function I get a lexical error, how can I make sure it keeps the value assigned to it after a button has clicked

```
export function categoryRender(){
    let filter = 'RICK'
    console.log(filter)
    const all = document.getElementById('all');
    all.onclick = function(){
        filter = 'ALL'
        render(filter);
    }
    categories = categories.sort();
    const filterContainer = document.getElementById("filter-container");
    filterContainer.innerHTML = "";
    const allFilterImg = document.getElementById('all-image');
    if (filter === 'ALL'){
        allFilterImg.setAttribute('src', './images/checked.jpeg')
    }else{
        allFilterImg.setAttribute('src', './images/unchecked.png')
        console.log('unchecked all firing')
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
        const line = document.createElement("span");
        const filterButton = document.createElement("img");
        const filterLabel = document.createElement("h2");
        filterContainer.appendChild(line);
        line.appendChild(filterButton);
        line.appendChild(filterLabel);
        line.setAttribute('id', categories[i]);
        line.classList.add('filter-line'); 
        filterLabel.innerHTML = categories[i]; 
        if (filter === categories[i]){
            filterButton.setAttribute('src', './images/checked.jpeg')
        }else{
            filterButton.setAttribute('src', './images/unchecked.png')
        }
        line.onclick = function(){
            filter = categories[i];
            render(filter)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What about the code doesn't work? May you share a runnable [mcve]?

Comment: Moving `let filter = ...` outside the function should just work.

Comment: simply moving the variable definition to just before the function gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'p' before initialization"